# Constantly listen to the server and update component in React Js

Tags: reactjs

So I am learning React and was wondering about keeping a component in sync with the db. Is there a way other than constantly making an ajax call to the server using an interval , to update the component state? Also, what would be the ideal way to approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would one use the Publish/Subscribe pattern (in JS/jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512949/why-would-one-use-the-publish-subscribe-pattern-in-js-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna do something like push notification, you could use to https://socket.io/
And send a notification from the server to front, if anything happens.

Comment: Wouldn't keeping a two way connection/ stream open be a bit of an overkill just to keep a check on the state? 
P.S. What would be the impact of such a connection on the server load?