# what does the callbacks add function do exactly?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery and found `callbacks.add()` but could not understand properly in http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.add/

So can anyone give me a proper example so that I could understand about it.

Comment: What in particular do you not understand? It adds another function or multiple functions to the list. That's it really. If you are just learning jQuery, you don't need `$.Callbacks` **at all**.

Comment: I want learn jquery deeply so I was seeing for this but the link I provided is not describing about it so much as in other description.

Comment: `$.Callbacks` is basically not jQuery related. It's just a utility function under the `jQuery` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, callbacks.fire() will call a function (or series of functions) in a row.
Callbacks.add(function) adds another callback to the chain.
 [Here is a page that describes how callbacks work in javascript:](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

They are a means of calling already defined functions. So, imagine you have the following function:

```
function hello(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Now, in order to call that function, you can use a Callback like so:

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add(hello);
```

But, when you fire that function, you have to specify the argument as defined in the hello function. So hence, it would be:

```
callbacks.fire("Hello all");
```

Another example/use of callback functions is when you have animations or effects and you want an effect to occur *after* another effect has completed. For example, you have a paragraph element and you want to hide it. But after the paragraph is hidden, you want an alert stating that it's hidden. So here you would use a callback function.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow",function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");  // call-back function after p is hidden.
    });
});
```

Comment: So, we can use like this: $('p').hide('slow', callbacks.add(hello);

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be helpful for you

[When would I use JQuery.Callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070894/when-would-i-use-jquery-callbacks)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/